# Accessing Spark's Panel Title Bar

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

How do I get access to the s:Panel's title bar? I want to add event listeners ONLY to the title bar and not to the entire panel. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to access the [skin parts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Panel.html#SkinPartSummary) directly.  Take a look at the PanelSkin class; as the source should be included in the SDK.  It appears the only element that may allow interaction is the titleDisplay; the rest of the title bar consists of FXG or MXML graphics.